# How to add spaces between texts?

Tags: android, react-native, text

I have texts listed one below the other. I want the spaces between the list to be bigger but I have no idea how to do it.

```
const CustomInput = () => {
      return (
         <View style={styles.container}>
         <Text>Book Titles</Text>
         <Text>Genre</Text>
        <Text>Author</Text>
        <Text>Number of pages</Text>
        </View>
    );
    
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        width: '100%',
        height: '50%',

        borderColour: '#e8e8e8',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 5,

        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        marginVertical: 5,
    },

});

export default CustomInput;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertically space added between your text

```
const CustomInput = () => {
      return (
         <View style={styles.container}>
         <Text>Book Titles</Text>
         <Text>Genre</Text>
        <Text>Author</Text>
        <Text>Number of pages</Text>
        </View>
    );
    
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        width: '100%',
        height: '50%',

        borderColour: '#e8e8e8',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 5,
        justifyContent:'space-between',
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        marginVertical: 5,
    },

});

export default CustomInput;
```

Horizontally space added between your text

```
const CustomInput = () => {
      return (
         <View style={styles.container}>
         <Text>Book Titles</Text>
         <Text>Genre</Text>
        <Text>Author</Text>
        <Text>Number of pages</Text>
        </View>
    );
    
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        width: '100%',
        height: '50%',
        flexDirection:'row',
        borderColour: '#e8e8e8',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 5,
        justifyContent:'space-between',
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        marginVertical: 5,
    },

});

export default CustomInput;
```